# Can I change connectParams while connecting using socket.io-client-swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, socket.io

I am creating a chat using sockets.
Enter your nickname using connectParams.
I want to change my nickname while connected to the socket.
How can I change it?

```
func connectSocket(){
    manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: url!)!, config: [.compress, .connectParams(["chatUID":chatUID,"isAdmin":isAdmin,"nickName":nickName])])
    socketClient = manager?.socket(forNamespace: "/chat")

    socketClient?.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
        if isJoin{
            self.sendJoinUser()
        }
    }
    socketClient?.connect()
}
```

i tried this

```
func changeNickname(newNickName:String){
     manager?.config = [.compress, .connectParams(["chatUID":chatUID,"isAdmin":isAdmin,"nickName":newNickName])]
     socketClient?.setReconnecting(reason: "Change NickName")
}
```

not worked

How can I change the parameters in real time?

Answer (score 1):

1st disconnect the socketClient.

```
socketClient?.disconnect()
```

Then redefine it with new parameter.

```
manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: url!)!, config: [.compress, .connectParams(["chatUID":chatUID,"isAdmin":isAdmin,"nickName": newNickName])])
socketClient = manager?.socket(forNamespace: "/chat")
```

Again connect it.

```
socketClient?.connect()
```

Very Simple.